# How to install MetaHookSv in Counter-Strike 1.6 Using a Non-Steam Scheme (Linux/Wine and MS Windows)?

Tags: steam, counter-strike, counter-strike-condition-zero

How do I install MetaHookSv in Counter-Strike 1.6 Using a Non-Steam Scheme (Linux/Wine and MS Windows)

I can't find any place where we have this information or even this consolidated and complete information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Install MetaHookSv in Counter-Strike 1.6: A Non-Steam Scheme (Linux/Wine and M$ Windows)

**IMPORTANT:**

- You should make a backup if you are not using the indicated version (below) of Counter-Strike 1.6;
- When using MetaHookSv and the Goldberg Steam Emulator with the Steam network you may be at risk of VAC.

#### Download CS 1.6 Steam BUILD 8684

Download CS 1.6 Steam BUILD 8684 [here](https://github.com/DevilBoy-eXe/Counter-Strike-1.6/releases/download/8684/Counter-Strike.1.6.zip) .

Unzip the `Counter-Strike.1.6.zip` file.

#### Install MetaHookSv

Download the latest version of MetaHookSv [here](https://github.com/hzqst/MetaHookSv/archive/main.zip).

Unzip the `MetaHookSv-main.zip` file.

Copy the files/folders...

```
./MetaHookSv-main/Build/platform
./MetaHookSv-main/Build/FreeImage.dll
./MetaHookSv-main/Build/SDL2.dll
./MetaHookSv-main/Build/svencoop.exe
```

... to the `./Counter-Strike 1.6` folder.

Copy the folders...

```
./MetaHookSv-main/Build/svencoop/captionmod
./MetaHookSv-main/Build/svencoop/metahook
./MetaHookSv-main/Build/svencoop/renderer
```

... to the `./Counter-Strike 1.6/cstrike` folder.

Rename the `./Counter-Strike 1.6/cstrike/metahook/configs/plugins\_goldsrc.lst` file to `./Counter-Strike 1.6/cstrike/metahook/configs/plugins.lst` and delete the others.

#### Install the Goldberg Steam Emulator

Download the latest MetaHookSv [here](http://mr_goldberg.gitlab.io/goldberg_emulator/).  (look for the link *-->Latest Build <--* ).

Unzip the `Goldberg_Lan_Steam_Emu_master--<BUILD_HASH>.zip` file.

Copy the `./Counter-Strike 1.6/steam_api.dll` file to the folder `./Goldberg_Lan_Steam_Emu_master--<BUILD_HASH>/tools`.

In the folder `./Goldberg_Lan_Steam_Emu\master--<BUILD\_HASH>/tools` run the command...

**Linux (Terminal/Wine)**

```
wine generate_interfaces_file.exe steam_api.dll.valve
```

**MS Windows (CMD)**

```
generate_interfaces_file.exe steam_api.dll.valve
```

... and copy the generated `steam_interfaces.txt` file to the `./Counter-Strike 1.6` folder.

Copy the file `./Goldberg_Lan_Steam_Emu_master--<BUILD_HASH>/steam_api.dll` (or `steam_api64.dll`) to the folder `./Counter-Strike 1.6`.

**NOTE:** The indicated Counter-Strike 1.6 already has a `steam_appid.txt` file. If not, you would need to create one from the example `./Goldberg_Lan_Steam_Emu\master--7c419e0a/steam_appid.EDIT_AND_RENAME.txt`.

### Start Counter-Strike 1.6

In the folder `./Counter-Strike 1.6` run the command...

**Linux (Terminal/Wine)**

```
export __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0 && export WINEDEBUG=-all && export __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 && export mesa_glthread=true && wine svencoop.exe -console -game cstrike
```

**MS Windows (CMD)**

```
svencoop.exe -console -game cstrike
```

---

**TIP:** Other useful suggested parameters (adapt/use as per your need)...

- `-gl` - Sets the rendered to OpenGL;
- `-full` - Forces the engine to start in fullscreen mode;
- `-w <WIDTH>` - Forces the engine to start with resolution set to width;
- `-h <HEIGHT>` - Forces the engine to start with resolution set to height;
- `-freq <FREQUENCY>` - Your display/video card refresh rate in Hz;
- `-toconsole` - Opens the console right when the game is launched;
- `-noforcemparms` - Forces the engine to use operating system mouse parameters;
- `-noforcemaccel` - Forces the engine to use operating system mouse acceleration;
- `-noforcemspd` - Forces the engine to use operating system mouse speed.

**A Linux (Terminal/Wine) Complete Example...**

```
export __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=0 && export WINEDEBUG=-all && export __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 && export mesa_glthread=true && wine svencoop.exe -game cstrike -gl -full -w 1920 -h 1080 -freq 75 -noforcemparms -noforcemaccel -noforcemspd
```

**More parameters** [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#GoldSrc_Games)**.**

---

#### Other Useful and Cool Info

**CS 1.6 Steam BUILD 8684 with MetaHookSv is compatible with the latest version of AMX Mod X**

Latest versions of AMX Mod X [here](https://www.amxmodx.org/downloads-new.php?branch=master). For more information visit [GitHub](https://github.com/alliedmodders/amxmodx).

**NOTE:** The AMX Mod X needs "metamod-p" in its [latest version](https://github.com/Bots-United/metamod-p/releases). For more information visit [GitHub](https://github.com/Bots-United/metamod-p).

**CS 1.6 Steam BUILD 8684 with MetaHookSv is compatible with the latest version (v1.50) of CSBot (via CS Bot Enabler)**

**NOTE:** The CS Bot Enabler needs "metamod-p" in its [latest version](https://github.com/Bots-United/metamod-p/releases). For more information visit [GitHub](https://github.com/Bots-United/metamod-p).

Latest version (v1.50) of CSBot [here](https://www.sitecs.net/downloads/CSBOTv1.5-SITECS.NET.zip).

Latest version of CS Bot Enabler [here](https://github.com/Arkshine/CSBotEnabler/releases).

[Here](https://gamebanana.com/mods/348361) we have *CSBotEnabler + GUI* which is a full scheme (**R E C O M M E N D E D**) with GUI to use CSBot (via CS Bot Enabler).

### Legal Clarification

MetaHookSv and Goldberg Steam Emulator are perfectly legal as they are authorial and new re-implementations via reverse engineering. Reverse engineering is accepted as a legal activity as it replicates the behavior of a given market component via a new and authored implementation. The use of reverse engineering has many, many favorable precedents. Examples of the legal use of reverse engineering include [Mame](https://www.mamedev.org/) and [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).